# pubsubclient won't compile in Arduino and VSCode IDEs

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, compilation-errors

I've compiled successfully a year ago in Arduino IDE, but lately I'm getting fatal errors:

```
/Users/davidjeffers/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.cpp: At global scope:
/Users/davidjeffers/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.cpp:473:8: error: redefinition of 'size_t PubSubClient::write(uint8_t)'
size_t PubSubClient::write(uint8_t data) {
^


In file included from /Users/davidjeffers/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.cpp:7:0:
/Users/davidjeffers/Documents/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:160:19: error: 'virtual size_t PubSubClient::write(uint8_t)' previously defined here
virtual size_t write(uint8_t) {};
^
```

I've tried using VSCode. I've tried opening an issue on GitHub.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: thanks. I'm having difficulty previewing.

Comment: reinstall the library

Comment: @Juraj - That works. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library is somehow modified. There should be no {} in `virtual size_t write(uint8_t) {};` or the whole line shouldn't be in this .h.

Reinstall the library.